# Ubuntu 23.10 used USB 2.0 for external SSD

Tags: usb, ssd

Outputs:

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:9210 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL9210 M.2 NVME Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1532:0a24 Razer USA, Ltd Razer BlackWidow V3 Tenkeyless
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0b05:1939 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c539 Logitech, Inc. Lightspeed Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1038:1430 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries Stratus Duo
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lsusb -v

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.10
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            6.05
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 6.5.0-26-generic xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:14.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x001f
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:9210 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL9210 M.2 NVME Adapter
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
```

Do I understand correctly that my external NVME SSD uses usb 2 instead of 3? Why does that happen? This is SSD where my linux is installed